# getting attribute error while using response.json() in python

Tags: python

I am using python to create a program which checks if the username and password field is empty or not and i am doing this
i have a function do_login which returns response but if the fields are empty it returns a custom response but i am getting error while i am testing for empty fields i can use any other validation like doing it in start but the do_something_with_this_error() will have to create differently.

```
        def do_login(username, password, callback):
            if(username == "" and password == ""):
                response = {"resultCode":401,'status': 'error', 'error': 'Please enter a username and password'}
                response = json.dumps(response)
                callback(response)
            else:
                url = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
                payload = json.dumps({"username": username, "password": password})
                headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
                callback(requests.post(url+"/users/getuser", data=payload,headers=headers))

        def login_button_fuction():
          
            def on_response(response):
                if response.json()["resultCode"] == 100:
                    print("success")
                else:
                    error = (response.json()["error"])
                    do_something_with_this_error()
```

and the error is

```
 if response.json()["resultCode"] == 100:
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'json'
```

Comment: You can debug and check the content in the "response"

Comment: @AghilVarghese tried and content are there but not working.

Comment: As I understood you are receiving a str response. Not json.
response.json() returns a JSON object of the result (if the result was written in JSON format, if not it raises an error).  @lexi

Comment: @AghilVarghese how can i return in json insted of str